# Android: can't change permission on /dev/ttyS0

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface, chmod

i'm using Olinuxino-A20 ( or Cubieboard-2, they are with same Android image). I want to write something to /dev/ttyS0. I'm using JNI methods, written in C. 
In my .cpp file I get permission denied.

```
fd = open(tty, O_RDWR);
....
f(fd < 0){
    LOGE("Failed to open serial console!");
    LOGE(strerror(errno));
    return -1;
} else
    LOGI("Serial port opened!");
```

So this return "permission denied".

In my Activity I try to gain access with:

```
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
new String[] { "su", "-c", "chmod 777 /dev/ttyS*" });
    Log.i("root", "Success chmod.");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
Log.e("root", "Fail to gain access");
}
```

And still nothing happens.
The version of the Android is 4.2.2, with kernel 3.3. Yes this device is rooted. I've used almost the same code with Olinuxino-A13 (4.0.3 with kernel 3.0), and there this works.

Also when I open serial terminal and enter manually the command: **chmod 777 /dev/ttyS*** and then run the app everything is working perfectly.

Can someone give me some advice why my code isn't working ?